# Можно ли как то зарефакторить этот код?

Tags: javascript, css

Кнопка создана по средствам leaflet, могу ли, я что то сделать со стилистикой этой кнопки? Как то вынести в отдельный файл css? знаю, что могу, не понимаю как)

```
function buttonUpDownLoad() {
    var ctrl = L.control({ position: 'topright' });
    ctrl.onAdd = function (map) {
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'mapbuttons leaflet-bar leaflet-control leaflet-control-custom');
        div.textContent = 'Download';
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        div.style.padding = '5px 10px';
        div.title = "ToDo";
        // div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../images/reload.png)';
    
        div.onclick = function () {
            downloadBinFile('polygon.csv', 'text/csv;charset=utf-8', latlng[0]);
        }
        return div;
    };
    ctrl.addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: в браузере по нужной кнопке ПКМ > исследовать > css > вычислено. примерно так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал вместо прямой установки стилей для элемента так же прямо установить ему класс. А потом отдельно где-нибудь в CSS файле стилизовать этот класс.

Comment: Отлично, может быть еще что то упростить можно?

Comment: Да нет, не особо, насколько я помню. Если у вас в проекте используется какой-нибудь фреймворк типа Vue или React'а, то можно выносить такие контролы в отдельные компоненты. В противном случае придется в любом случае работать с DOM через JS (что в наше время само по себе немножко анти-паттерн, но что поделать).